# Difficulty displaying a date in a Cognos BI 10.2.2 crosstab node member

Tags: label, pivot-table, cognos, cognos-10

I am encountering a challenge while attempting to display a date in a specific crosstab node member in Cognos BI 10.2.2. I consistently encounter an issue where the column displays "--" instead of the desired date.

I have experimented with different date formats and sizes, but the problem persists. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to successfully display the date within the crosstab node member. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Despite trying various approaches such as placing the date in the member caption, report expression, data item value, query calculation, label calculation within a text item, and singleton.

Curiously, if I place the same data item in the title or outside the crosstab, it appears correctly. My intention is to present the date as the previous year (e.g., 2022 if the current year is 2023). This is a relatively simple requirement, but I have been unable to achieve the desired result.

Comment: There are several problems you could be trying to describe.  Please reproduce the problem using the GO Sales (query) package and post the report spec as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to change the column header or the column data itself to the previous year.  If it is just the column header, it would be easier to use a report expression, instead of messing with the member.  The -- usually indicates the crosstab cannot determine what is being asked based on the row and column edge context.